# Eclipse Android Debug Not Launching - No Errors, No Logs, Nothing

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I couldn't find the answer to this on SO, so I thought I would submit a question/answer.
I'm not sure if this is version specific, so just in case it is I'm running Eclipse 3.7.2 and ADT 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
Developing for ICS.
I spent a good portion of the morning running trying to debug my app. I would go up to the little green bug, and click on my project.
The Launch indicator starts at the bottom, fills all the way up to 100% then nothing. No errors, no log output, no logcat messages, nothing under console. For the most part, there is no output indication that something has gone wrong. It just doesn't launch.
I have been switching between and HTC device and an emulator for debugging - mostly using the device for tests right before a release.
So I thought I would plug the HTC in and try again. Plugged it in, logcat started rolling, clicked on the de-bug, same thing. No output, no logs, nothing. It just doesn't launch.

Answer (score 0):

Answer.
I finally decided to (though this should have probably been one of the first things I did, however because there were no errors or log outputs, I thought this was something exotic.) check the debug configurations. Turns out that under the Target tab, the deployment mode somehow got switched to Automatic. However, I had recently deleted a virtual device. This lead to an Automatic launch, with no device selected for the launch. Thus, the launch was automated with no end point.
To me, it seems there should be some sort of error message for this sort of thing, something like, "You have not selected a device" or "Please select a device", which is why I immediately suspected a more serious issue - but hey, I'm just a developer.
At any rate, all I had to do, obviously, was to set it back to Manual and voila, she's a kickin' again.
Some may think this is a no brainer, while others more slightly crazy with a tendency to distort reality may end up having the same problem I did. So, in sympathy to the crazy/distorted reality type - here's the answer :)